# Select the first record based of dulpicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am trying to solve a duplicate issue in SQL server.

I have a lot of duplicate records with the exact information except the column time like:

[image]

I would like to select the record that has the max datetime for each subset of duplicates.

I tried to use the `MAX()` aggregation but that does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, though, on second glance your question is simpler than the duplicate I suggested, and even the "at first glance" solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column/7745635#7745635) would work.

Comment: The suggested answer is much more complicated than this question requires. Is it too late to change it?

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT [id], [name], MAX([date])
FROM [table_name]
GROUP BY [id], [name]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(date) as maxdate FROM mytable GROUP BY id, name
```

This should give you exactly the results you describe, in SQL Server.